# Images not showing in Winforms

Tags: winforms, image, resources

I am using Winforms (C#.NET). When I add resources (images) to the resource viewer I can see them.

[image]

But when I add them to a form, only a grey background is visible - images are not.

[image]

But when load images from local resources it shows fine. I think the problem is with project resource file. Is anything wrong with me??

---

Edit: This is the designer code...

```
 <data name="addemployee" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
<value>..\Resources\addemployee1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>


</data>
  <data name="addmovie" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\addmovie1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="buytickets" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\buytickets1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="changepassword" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\changepassword1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="customerregistration" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\customerregistration1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="deleteemployee" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\deleteemployee1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="movietheater" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\movietheater1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="welcomeadmin" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\welcomeadmin1.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="welcomeform3" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\welcomeform31.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="welcomeform4" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\welcomeform41.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

Comment: Just try pressing OK and see if it magically shows up :) @Duane: It's the "Select Resource" form. No code involved.

Comment: I didn't use any code for inserting images into the background.

Comment: @minitech I pressed Ok but the grey background still there. But in properties, background image shows none

Comment: The image is not in the App's Resource Directory ( The path) !

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: What makes you say that?

Comment: @MohanRajK: Try a smaller image, and also try restarting Visual Studio, and also try an image an a different format, and also try a local path to an image instead of one from your resources. Also check the `.Designer.cs` file and see what `BackgroundImage` is being set to. (This looks like a VS bug to me, though.)

Comment: @minitech Thanks.. Restarting VS solves this problem.. but I still don't know why it first shows plain background..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bug with Visual studio. Try restarting will help this..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the properties of the image to resource instead of content and give it a shot

Comment: do you mean change the properties of the image in designer window??

Comment: thats correct!!! or you can select the image and hit f4 and in the properties pane change the property build action from content to resource